# Регулярные выражения Java для парсинга объектов

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, текст

Дали задание на курсах. Сами правила регулярок знаю, но практики с ними не было.

Есть задание - поиск товаров из файла по критерию.

**Данные**

```
Oven : POWER_CONSUMPTION=2000, WEIGHT=11, CAPACITY=33, DEPTH=60, HEIGHT=40, WIDTH=70  
Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=1.5, OS=Linux, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1000, CPU=2.2, DISPLAY_INCHES=19 
Laptop : BATTERY_CAPACITY=3, OS=Windows, MEMORY_ROM=8000, SYSTEM_MEMORY=1500, CPU=3.2, DISPLAY_INCHES=22  
TabletPC : BATTERY_CAPACITY=5, DISPLAY_INCHES=16, MEMORY_ROM=16000, FLASH_MEMORY_CAPACITY=8, COLOR=green
```

По моему алгоритму, сначала стоит вычленить названия объектов, а после вычленить из строки с названием данные из заданного критерия (*к примеру, если мне нужен ноут с памятью больше 1ТБ, то мне должна вывестись третья строка*)

Подскажите пожалуйста, как:

1. Вычленить все **имена** объектов (*Oven, Laptop, TabletPC*)
2. Вычленить данные из параметров объекта (*из строки после ":" найти все параметры и их значения [param=value]*)

> UPD:
> Практически пришел к решению первой задачи, но за исключением того, что не *"ловится"* первая строчка.
> Вот решение `\n[A-Za-z]{1,}`

Comment: 1) `const names = text.match(/^\w+/gm)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Вычленить все имена объектов (Oven, Laptop, TabletPC)

```
^\w+
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5b97j

> Вычленить данные из параметров объекта (из строки после ":" найти все
> параметры и их значения [param=value])

```
(\S+)=([^,\s]+)
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5b97m